# C# Wpf PasswordBox quero espiar a senha

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Boa noite, tenho alguns PasswordBox e gostaria de adicionar botoes de espiar essa senha quando o usuário precisar, tentei invocar o  PasswordRevealMode dentro do PasswordBox, porem ele não reconhece como comando conhecido, gostaria de saber se foi descontinuado ou se tenho que fazer algo antes e se isso aconteceu como posso fazer para espiar essa senha.

Comment: [PasswordRevealMode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.passwordbox.passwordrevealmode#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_PasswordBox_PasswordRevealMode) e [IsPasswordRevealButtonEnabled](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.passwordbox.ispasswordrevealbuttonenabled#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_PasswordBox_IsPasswordRevealButtonEnabled) são propriedades específicas do [PasswordBox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.passwordbox) da plataforma UWP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com o `PasswordBox` não é possível fazer. Talvez você até consiga fazer algum "workaround" com `TextBox` usando dois deles onde um realmente armazena a senha e o outro coloca apenas **'*'** a cada caractere digitado, **mas isso não é recomendado devido a questões de segurança**.

Veja mais informações no link abaixo:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/98d0d4d4-1463-481f-b8b1-711119a6ba99/password-box-and-visible-password?forum=wpf